# React Screen Blank

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm a beginner in react router and i don't know why , when i execute my code my screens appear to be white..
I tried everything but it still showing me same white blank screen again and again if anyone know how to deal with it please let me know Thanks!:)

```
import LearningComponent from './Component/LearningComponent';

import Header from './Component/header';
import Footer from './Component/footer';
import {BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Link
 } from "react-router-dom"

function App() {
  
  return (
   <div>
    <Header />
    <LearningComponent name="Naeem" />
    <Router>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to="/" className='text-blue-500'>Home</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/about" className='text-blue-500'>About</Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <Routes>
      <Route exact path='/'>
<h1>This is the Home Page</h1>
      </Route>
      <Route path='/about'>
<h1>This is the About Page</h1>
      </Route>
    </Routes>
    </Router>
    <Footer />
   </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: That's no how routes work. Please read the [documentation](https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/getting-started/tutorial).

Comment: You probably have errors in the browser's console

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

In `react-router-dom@6` the `Route` component API changed significantly. There are no longer any `component`, and `render` and `children` function props, all replaced by a single `element` prop taking a `React.ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX, as a prop value, and  only other `Route` components are valid children in the case of nested routes.

## Solution

Render the routed components *as JSX* on the `Route` component's `element` prop.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path='/' element={<h1>This is the Home Page</h1>} />
  <Route path='/about' element={<h1>This is the About Page</h1>} />
</Routes>
```